# Effect of Cosmological Expansion at the Atomic Level

Tags: cosmology, atoms, space-expansion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does space expansion not expand matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2110/why-does-space-expansion-not-expand-matter)

Does cosmological expansion have any effects at the atomic level?

Answer (score 0):

No. See: [Expansion of the space-time metric](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3518/expansion-of-the-space-time-metric/3520#3520) and [Why does space expansion not expand matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2110/why-does-space-expansion-not-expand-matter).